# How to return 'true/false' for each value, if it appears at a groups in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, boolean

My goal is to check for a list of values whether they appear in certain value groups, and to answer that question in a true / false Boolean value when all groups are displayed.
Here is a very simple example:

The following is a list of actors names, and the films in which they appear:
My goal is to return a table that contains the following columns:
The name of the film, the name of the actor, and a column "did he play in the film"?
You can see in the result table, that all the actors appear for each movie, even if they are not playing it, and all movie names appear, even if there was not any player in them.
When sorting by movie name, and sub-sorted by player name,
thank you very much for your advice,

```css
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
    <style type="text/css">
     table.tableizer-table {
      font-size: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC; 
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     } 
     .tableizer-table td {
      padding: 4px;
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
     }
     .tableizer-table th {
      background-color: #104E8B; 
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: bold;
     }
    </style>
    <table class="tableizer-table">
    <thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Actor</th><th>Movie Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>
     <tr><td>Brad Pitt</td><td>inglourious basterds</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Matt Damon</td><td>Ocean's Eleven</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td><td>The Departed</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Brad Pitt</td><td>Ocean's Eleven</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Matt Damon</td><td>The Departed</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Christoph Waltz </td><td>inglourious basterds</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td><td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

```
    <style type="text/css">
     table.tableizer-table {
      font-size: 12px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC; 
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     } 
     .tableizer-table td {
      padding: 4px;
      margin: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #CCC;
     }
     .tableizer-table th {
      background-color: #104E8B; 
      color: #FFF;
      font-weight: bold;
     }
    </style>
    <table class="tableizer-table">
    <thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Movie Name</th><th>Actor</th><th>did he played?</th></tr></thead><tbody>
     <tr><td>inglourious basterds</td><td>Brad Pitt</td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>inglourious basterds</td><td>Christoph Waltz </td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>inglourious basterds</td><td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>inglourious basterds</td><td>Matt Damon</td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Ocean's Eleven</td><td>Brad Pitt</td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Ocean's Eleven</td><td>Christoph Waltz </td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Ocean's Eleven</td><td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Ocean's Eleven</td><td>Matt Damon</td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Departed</td><td>Brad Pitt</td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Departed</td><td>Christoph Waltz </td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Departed</td><td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Departed</td><td>Matt Damon</td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td><td>Brad Pitt</td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td><td>Christoph Waltz </td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td><td>Leonardo DiCaprio</td><td>TRUE</td></tr>
     <tr><td>The Wolf of Wall Street</td><td>Matt Damon</td><td>FALSE</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **A screenshot can’t be run as code.**

Comment: Edit your question and show the schema of each table, and the SQL statement you have tried. If you post as text as @tadman suggests, we should be able to provide an answer.

Comment: @SloanThrasher
i have edited my post, hope its more clear now, 
thank you,

Comment: @tadman 
any idea about the current question? thanks!

Comment: Itay Av, you may have edited your post, but I do not see the schemas of the tables, or the SQL statement you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You could cross join the table with itself and use the `exists` operator on a correlated query:

```
SELECT a.actor, b.movie, EXISTS (SELECT *
                                 FROM   mytable c
                                 WHERE  a.actor = c.actor AND b.movie = c.movie) AS played
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT actor FROM mytable) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT movie FROM mytable) b
```

Comment: Your solution works great!
I wanted to find out, if I'm interested thant in the column
"did he played"
The "true / false" values appear instead of the 1/0 values (that appear with your solution),
I tried to wrap the definition of the column "played" using the "CASE" function,
That is, when the value is 1, i will display "true", otherwise display "false"
However, I get an error message of wrong syntax in MYSQL,
What is the required syntax?
thanks in advance,

Comment: @ItayAv you could use `case exists (select ...) when 1 then 'true' else 'false' end`.

Comment: excellent! i missed the 'end' at the expression, now it works fine,
thank you for your time and efforts